# Adding blocks or content panes to a Views page in Drupal 7

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I am using Drupal 7.34 and a bootstrap theme to develop a website for an organization. I have a custom content type which displays people's profiles, and a view page which currently displays all the profiles created from this custom content type. The link to this page is on the main menu. I have created a taxonomy which categorizes people into current and alumni (for example).

I want to organize this as follows:

1. When users navigate to the People page, they are shown the profiles of all current people first. I am using bootstrap grid for this.
2. After this, I want to display as a seperate group all alumni, with the title Alumni.

Like this: [image: Wireframe for People Page]

I have been able to create the view page with all profiles, but am unable to create the Alumni section.

Could you give me some pointers?

Comment: Is this what you are talking about: https://www.drupalgardens.com/documentation/taxonomy/views ? Basically you group your view by taxonomy and use the term as the header in that view recipe found on that page. If that is what you are referring to then that page may help get it setup. Not sure if the bootstrap grid can be put in there but maybe the setup is the same.

Comment: I suggest you create 2 block view's. 1 for the people only and 2nd one for the alumni only. Then just add the blocks to your node.

Comment: Or create a page view for the people list, then add an attachment of alumni after.